# Sendkeys for Windows Start key

Tags: c#, sendkeys

I'm trying to use the `Sendkeys` to simulate the `Windows` start key, but none of the options I tried work, does anybody know how can it be done?

**CODE**

```
    [System.Runtime.InteropServices.DllImport("user32.dll")]
    private Thread thrTyping;

    private void startThread()
    {
        ThreadStart ts = new ThreadStart(sendKeys);
        thrTyping = new Thread(ts);
        thrTyping.Start();
    }

    private void sendKeys()
    {
       // TEST 1
       Thread.Sleep(5000);
       SendKeys.SendWait("(^)"+"{ESC}");           

       // TEST 2
       Thread.Sleep(5000);
       SendKeys.SendWait("{LWin}");
    }
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use [keybd_event](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms646304%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) instead:

```
private const int KEYEVENTF_EXTENDEDKEY = 0x1;
private const int KEYEVENTF_KEYUP = 0x2;

[DllImport("user32.dll")]
static extern void keybd_event(byte bVk, byte bScan, uint dwFlags, int dwExtraInfo);

private static void PressKey(byte keyCode)
{
    keybd_event(keyCode, 0x45, KEYEVENTF_EXTENDEDKEY, 0);
    keybd_event(keyCode, 0x45, KEYEVENTF_EXTENDEDKEY | KEYEVENTF_KEYUP, 0);
}
```

[List of KeyCodes](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd375731%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) (The one you are looking for is 0x5B - left win key)