# Send keys syntax needed

Tags: automation, blueprism

I am using Global send keys event in Blueprism and need to press Windows button.
For example Control key is {CTRL}. What is the syntax for Windows key?

Does anyone have the full list of keystrokes syntax.

Comment: Wiki says, when keyboard lacks that key, combination of CTRL+ESC performs the same function. Try it and give us a feed back.

Comment: Let's hope this will be the answer, but as far as google CTRL+ESC cannot be combined with other buttons. I mean, the WIN+D is not the same as CTRL+ESC+D

Comment: Using CTRL+ESC worked. Windows key can be pressed using CTRL+ESC. Thanks @RAFEL

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the BluePrism uses standard C# implementation of sendkeys. If you'd like to read more sendkeys class, then you can find the information on [Microsoft Developer Network](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.sendkeys(v=vs.110).aspx).

The standard implementation does not allow using windows key, so to do that you'll need to work around that with BluePrism code stages, and write a code in one of BluePrism supported coding languages (c#, j#, vb.net)

That question how to do that was answered several times already on stackoverflow. Some solutions are available on these pages: [Link 1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10366152/sending-windows-key-using-sendkeys), [Link 2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6407584/sendkeys-send-and-windows-key), [Link 3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24132775/sendkeys-for-windows-start-key)